# JButton inside JTable: Button working, but text vanishes on click

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton, settext

I have a Jtable with a button on each row to delete the row.
The Text is set to "Delete". When I select the button, the text vanishes. How can I set the text for selected button?

Renderer:

```
public class JButtonRenderer  extends JButton implements TableCellRenderer {

    public JButtonRenderer(){
        this.setText("Delete");
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable arg0, Object arg1, boolean arg2, boolean arg3, int arg4,
            int arg5) {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Editor:

```
public class DeleteButtonCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements
TableCellEditor {

private JButton button = new JButton();

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public DeleteButtonCellEditor(){
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
              //Perform Button Actions
        }
    });
}

@Override
public Object getCellEditorValue() {
    return "Delete";
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable arg0, Object arg1, boolean arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
    return button;
}
}
```

Comment: show your table model class

Comment: im using DefaultTableModel

Comment: text dissapper when you click button or select row ?

Comment: it disappears when I click the button. the text doesn't disappear if selecting the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use this class with `TableCellEditor`, `TableCellRenderer`

```
class JButtonRenderer extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor, TableCellRenderer {

        public JButtonRenderer() {
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            JButton b = new JButton("Delete");
            return b;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, final int row, int column) {
            JButton b = new JButton("Delete");
            b.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // code
                }
            });
            return b;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject anEvent) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

and using:

```
JButtonRenderer compCellDelete = new JButtonRenderer();

jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(your_column_index).setCellEditor(compCellDelete);
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(your_column_index).setCellRenderer(compCellDelete);
```